# Sending message to a new channel discord.py

Tags: discord.py

So ive made a channel nuke command and this is what i have

```
    channel = ctx.channel
    channel_position = channel.position
    
    new_channel = await channel.clone()
    await channel.delete()
    await new_channel.edit(position=channel_position, sync_permissions=True)
    await new_channel.ctx.send("Channel Nuked")
```

I was wondering how to make the bot send a message into the new channel

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `await new_channel.send("Channel Nuked")` instead of `await new_channel.ctx.send("Channel Nuked")`.